# How to Fail Build If Particular Method Is Used?

Tags: java, maven, build

I want the build to fail if someone calls `Executors.newFixedThreadPool()`, `newCachedThreadPool()`, etc. without a ThreadFactory. We have had issues in the past with thread leaks and unable to determine their origin because the threads were not named properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very specific task!

You could write your own maven build-plugin and look for the word "newFixedThreadPool" with only one argument in all java-files and fail if so.

I had those tasks too, id like noone to use `String.toUpperCase` without a locale, no Serializable without SerialVersionUID and no static imports, finally i wrote a development-handbook.

Comment: Is that going to be a regex? Do you have any samples? I've been doing some googling and it might be possible to add a detector to FindBugs or Checkstyle, but was hoping someone has already done this.

Comment: @joseph Its not a bug, it is not a "style" so a solution using Findbugs and Checkstyle will be a misuse or a workaround. From my experience: use a custom build-plugin. But i remember checkstyle allowes to have custom rules written in java.